# Python - Add a line behind a specific string with a consecutive numeric

Tags: python, string

I do have a little problem i can't solve in Python, iam not really familiar with this codes commands, that's one of the reasons this is kind of difficult for me.

For example, when i have a text file like this:

```
Indicate somename X1
Random qwerty
Indicate somename X2
random azerty
Indicate somename X3
random qwertz
Indicate somename X4
random asdfg
Indicate somename X5
```

I would like to make a script to get specific value's behind it, like this:

```
Indicate somename X1 value = 500
Random qwerty
Indicate somename X2 value = 500
random azerty
Indicate somename X3 value = 500
random qwertz
Indicate somename X4 value = 500
random asdfg
Indicate somename X5 value = 500
```

I already tried a script like this:

```
def replace_score(file_name, line_num, text):
 f = open(file_name, 'r')
 contents = f.readlines()
 f.close()

 contents[line_num] = text+"\n"

 f = open(file_name, "w")
 contents = "".join(contents)
 f.write(contents)
 f.close()

replace_score("file_path", 10, "replacing_text")
```

But I couldn't get it working the way i wanted it to do.

I hope someone can help me out,

Greeting,

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('sample') as fp, open('sample_out', 'w') as fo:
    for line in fp:
        if 'Indicate' in line:
            content = line.strip() + " = 500"
        else:
            content = line.strip()
        fo.write(content + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this one works fine for me. 
I already have the value 500, the indication of number with an %d command. 
However next thing for me to do is to put all those "idicate somename X" in an array, because those values should be different for each individual value, and there will be a couple of 100 of them, that's my next challange.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/tmp/content.txt') as f:   # where: '/tmp/content.txt' is the path of file
    for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        line = line.strip()
        if not (i % 2):
            line += ' value = 500'
        print line.strip()
# Output:
Indicate somename X1 value = 500
Random qwerty
Indicate somename X2 value = 500
random azerty
Indicate somename X3 value = 500
random qwertz
Indicate somename X4 value = 500
random asdfg
Indicate somename X5 value = 500
```

Answer (score 0):

using 're' module

eg.

```
 if re.match(r'Indicate somename [A-Z][0-2]', line):
     modified = line.strip() + ' value = XXX'
```

if you want require to modify input file in-place, 
read entry file in to buffer then write result back.

Comment: Good to know that the [A-Z] command exist! Either those number are very interesting i did not know that.
Is there a possibility with method to give, let's say 100, different "Indicate somename" a different individual value?